# how to run cmd in php exec function

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I am trying to run a command on windows which is the follwing :

```
 sfm+pmvs C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\temp\\$filename/ hello.nvm
```

I have done this but it wont work for me :

```
exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\temp\\draw\\VisualSFM_win32.exe sfm+pmvs C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\temp\\$filename/ hello.nvm");
```

when I do the following :

```
exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\temp\\draw\\VisualSFM_win32.exe");
```

it works just fine but I need the other paramters to be included in the command line

how could that be done in php and is there any way to open a cmd.exe and to run the command above ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Exec() just running in cmd command which you wrote as first argument of exec(). If VisualSFM_win32.exe not support arguments by run via cmd, you cannot run it as you want. Sorry for my english =)

You asked me for exapmle. My example below. 
I am not sure it is 100% right because i don't use windows last 3 years.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\draw\"
start VisualSFM_win32.exe sfm+pmvs C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\%1/ hello.nvm
```

and in php

```
exec("C:\\test.bat " . $filename);
```

Comment: I ran the same line in cmd and it worked just fine but in exec it is not working!!

Comment: you could try to write some script in BAT file and run it by using exec()

Comment: can you give me an example for my case please?!

Comment: Example is above this comments

Comment: but $filename is a php variable how could be used in the batch file?!